# Report server data driven subscription render format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We are using data driven subscription for reports. Reports with PDF as attachment is working, but reports with Excel as attachment is not working.

Comment: please clarify "not working"

Comment: Could you check the LastStatus column of the Subscriptions table in the ReportServer database?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832103/ssrs-subscriptions-table-and-executionlog3-view

Answer (score 0):

Use EXCELOPENXML as the render format for Excel.  This works for me with Data Driven subscriptions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

The EXCELOPENXML extension defines the Excel renderer for current (.xlsx) Excel files. The EXCEL extension defines the Excel 2003 version. Visible = "false" indicates the Excel 2003 renderer is hidden.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).